# How can I use "proof by contradiction" in an induction proof?

Tags: logic, induction

I am wondering how I can show the second statement as a proof by contradiction:
[image]

Do I have something like

$(\begin{align}\forall n\geq n_{0}:A(n)\implies A(n+1)\end{align})\iff(\forall n\geq n_{0}:A(n)\land\neg A(n+1))$

or is it

$(\begin{align}\forall n\geq n_{0}:A(n)\implies A(n+1)\end{align})\iff(\exists n_{1}<n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}:A(n)\land\neg A(n+1))$?

I am not sure how to negate the statment. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: When you talk about "the second statement", what do you refer to?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I meant part ii),i.e. the inductive step.

Comment: So, where does $n_0$ come from in your attempts? It does not appear in the statement (ii).

Comment: Yes, my bad. $n_{0}$ could be equal to 1. I think I had the slightly more genereal version in mind. It is the base case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to think of proof by induction as a proof by contradiction that the set of counterexamples of our statement must be empty.  Assume the set of counterexamples of $A(n): C= \{n \in \Bbb N \mid \lnot A(n) \}$ is non-empty.  Then $C$ is a non-empty set of non-negative integers, so it has to have a smallest element, $k$.

We prove directly that $A(0)$ is true so we know that $0$ can't be the least element of $C$; *i.e.*, $k \neq 0$.  Therefore $k$ must have the form $m+1$ for some $m \in \Bbb N$.  Since $m \notin C$ (because by assumption $k=m+1$ is the least element of $C$ and $m \lt m+1$), we know that $A(m)$ holds.  But in our inductive step we've proved that $A(m) \Rightarrow A(m+1)$, so since we know $A(m)$ holds, the proof of the inductive step tells us that $A(m+1)$ also holds.  But that contradicts $m+1=k \in C$.

Therefore, our initial assumption that $C \neq \varnothing$ must be false and our set of counterexamples must be empty; in other words, $A(n)$ holds $\forall n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Isn't that sort of the argument for showing that the induction principle is equivalent to the Well-Ordering-Principle? However, I don't quite see how this answers my question, since it was more about how correctly  negate the the statement/quantifiers, I think.

Comment: Yes, it's an equivalence I often find useful.  I'm not sure what statement you're trying to negate.  I thought you were asking how to reframe a proof by induction as a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Okay I see. What I would like to know is, if I can show part ii) by contradiction, i.e. show that $A(n)\land\neg A(n+1)$ is false. What somehow puzzles me is wheather I have $\exists n_{1}< n_{0}$, which I think comes from negating the entire statement or if I have $\forall n\geq n_{o}:A(n)\land\neg A(n+1)$.

Comment: @Hans Translate "whenever" in statement (ii) to mean $\forall$.  To prove the second statement by contradiction, assume that $ \exists k  ~(k \in S \land k+1 \notin S)$ and then derive a contradiction from that assumption.